# C# How make Regular Expression with special hostname

Tags: c#, regex, hostname

I'm having trouble finding a regular expression that works with my domain name. I do not know if I have a special domain name, but none of the examples I've found are working for me.

Here is my host name:

```
81-232197-178.cust.bluewin.ch
```

and here is my regex:

```
^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$
```

but it doesn't match.

Comment: Could you show us the regex you are currently using that doesn't match?

Comment: Sorry ! ("^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-][a-zA-Z0-9]).)([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$)

Comment: Can't you just include a literal in the expression?

Comment: ^ ^ I need for my application on Windows 8! I code a application network utility to retrieve information ,the ip adress, host name etc. .. I get the source code of the site, http://mon-ip.com and I research the value with a' RegularExpression

Comment: There are some problems with your regular expression.  It does not allow the hostname to start with a digit.  Also, it will only match two-segment name.  The dot (.) is a special character in a regular expression.  You need to put a backslash in front of it.  The first segment will only match one character or three character names (after you put in the backslash).  Try searching for "regular expression to match dns name".  They're out there.

Comment: ok i search now for a dns pattern

Comment: ^(?![0-9]+$)(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{,63}(?<!-)$ - No Work                 @"([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+):(.[^:]+)" - No Work  atc.. I think creating a pattern like this is far too complex to manage in the numbers of possibilities of formats. Thank you so much time stuck with me. Finally I go look for an alternative to the regular expression ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are screen-scraping that website, you're probably better looking for the adjacent text and taking the string out of the next element in the DOM, rather than trying to find a regular expression that matches just that text in the page.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of periods(.) is not variable you could use the pattern below:

```
([0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*).([0-9A-Za-z]*).([0-9A-Za-z]*).([0-9A-Za-z]*)
```

Comment: it returns me this as result:

 -8859-1 "/</br>
 31-05-2012 20</br>
 - One-click media</br>
 -> <iframe width</br>
 -8,366,558 To 2 ");</br> from the code source : http://www.mon-ip.com sorry but I need this pattern works for this domain and others too. Not just mine. Thank you very much for taking time for myself

Comment: I have found this and its WORK ! But i don't now if he work for another hostname/dns..  --->@"([0-9a-zA-Z.-_]{3,}[.]){3,6}[0-9a-zA-Z]{2,}